# How can I get the image recorded from a rear-view camera?

Tags: camera, wiring

I have a rear-view camera ([NAVITEL MR250](https://navitel.ru/en/devices/dvr/navitel-mr250)) which I use everyday. I got into image processing and I thought a good personal project would be to create a "self-driving car" (Quotation marks because I just wanted to do the image processing part). I took the recordings from the SD-Card and I did some basic lane-detection, and other safety measure.

My question is, is it possible to somehow hook into the live feed of the camera, so I can implement it in my car? I tried to look for any datasheets for this model but I couldn't find anything. As a last resort I will disassemble the camera, replace the electronics with a RPI and create my own rear-view camera.

I just want to say I have 0 experience with Pi (I know what it is, how it works, how I am supposed to use it, etc, and I did many small projects with Arduino)

Comment: I skimmed through the user guide and found your camera a pretty standard thing, just like a car parking or web camera.  A couple of years ago I used Rpi2 to play with both and found it easy to use with many popular newbie friendly open source video libraries. I have saved a penzu entry for your reference - https://penzu.com/p/67581cd1.

Comment: Yes it is a standard one (It also has a rear camera). This idea popped to my mind when I came for work today, as my original idea was to just use a Pi with another camera, besides the rear-view mirror (because that starts every time I start the car).
I will look into your comment when I get home. Thank you very much!

Comment: Logitech Brio 4K/1080p/720 USB2/3/3.1/C $200
https://support.logi.com/hc/en-hk/articles/360023462913-BRIO-4K-Pro-Webcam-Technical-Specifications
https://www.logitech.com/assets/65041/2/brio-refguide.ENG.pdf
Logitech C930e US$70
https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32969035958.html?spm=a2g0w.search0302.3.249.767110d4iaNEqJ&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_0_10084_10083_10887_10307_321_453_322_454_10618_536_10065_317_537_10068_319_10059_10103_10884_10696,searchweb201603_0,ppcSwitch_0&algo_pvid=8b238173-bd14-497a-9871-4090eec474b1&algo_expid=8b238173-bd14-497a-9871-4090eec474b1-27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most probably won't be able to.

You will have to find out many things up front:

- is there a video output (analog or digital)
- is there a connector to communicate with the device
- is the camera interface something common (the Pi will only work with CSI and USB)

If you cannot answer any of those questions with a **yes** then you will not succeed.
If you think you can use GPIO for any general purpose communication, than you are wrong. It is pretty hard if not damn impossible to get timings right. 1080p @ 30 FPS requires a huge bandwidth.
In contrast, getting the official Raspberry Pi Camera or any compatible up and running is totally easy.

Comment: When I get home or in this weekend I will disassemble the camera and see what interface the camera uses. I assumed it uses CSI (I know Pi can only use CSI and USB and that it is easy to set up because I was curious in doing a network of security cameras around my house a few months back so I looked into it), I don't know why I did that, maybe because it looks like a very generic camera.